# Excel VBA Insert Method Failure

Tags: python, vba, excel

I'm using xlwings and by extension the PyWin32 API to manipulate an Excel document. I want to create a function that, on Monday morning, takes an opened excel document and inserts a new column to the left of "volatile_column", then fills the new column with 0s.

Code thus far:

```
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw
import datetime as dtt
from pybev import datecheck


def monday_new_column(metrics):

    stripped_date = datecheck.date_to_datetime(dtt.datetime.today().date())

    if stripped_date.weekday() == 0:
        if stripped_date not in metrics.df.columns: # ensures no existing column
            col_num = int(np.where(metrics.df.columns == metrics.volatile_column)[0][0] + 2)
            max_row = int(len(metrics.df.index) + 2)

            # Using an xlwings constant & defining a column of zeroes
            xlShiftToRight = xw.constants.InsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight
            zero_array = np.zeros((max_row,), dtype=np.int)[np.newaxis].T

            print('Adding new week column...',end=''),

            # !! VBA code !!
            range_obj = metrics.sheet.range((1,col_num),(max_row,col_num))
            range_obj.api.Insert(Shift=xlShiftToRight) # here's the problem line
            range_obj.api.value = zero_array

            print('Done')

    return
```

Which dumps the error:

```
--> 191             range_obj.api.Insert(Shift=xlShiftToRight)
    192             range_obj.api.value = zero_array
    193 
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     61         while True:
     62             try:
---> 63                 v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
     64                 t = type(v)
     65                 if t is CDispatch:
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in Insert(self, Shift, CopyOrigin)
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in _ApplyTypes_(self, dispid, wFlags, retType, argTypes, user, resultCLSID, *args)
    280 
    281         def _ApplyTypes_(self, dispid, wFlags, retType, argTypes, user, resultCLSID, *args):
--> 282                 result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
    283                 return self._get_good_object_(result, user, resultCLSID)
    284 
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Insert method of Range class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

This is a VBA error, so I don't think that the surrounding python code is the issue. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-insert-method-excel) provides no clues as to what's happening, and googling the error just produces a lot of users running into issues with the `Select()` method, which I'm not using here.

I've also tried removing the `Shift=xlShiftToRight` argument and explicitly calling `metrics.sheet.range((1,col_num),(max_row,col_num))` every time instead of using the `range_obj` pointer. Both strategies return the same error message as the initial one.

Am I missing something simple with my syntax, or is this a deeper API issue?

Comment: Is this an existing spreadsheet?  If so, is the spreadsheet editable (not locked)?

Comment: are you able to insert a single cell on a blank worksheet?

Comment: Using an excel com object I was able to call `Insert()` on a range object without error.  I then protected the sheet from editing and tried the same `Insert()` again and got exact `com_error` you received including the error message that `'Insert method of Range class failed'`.  So my guess is that your sheet is protected.

Comment: Was on lunch. So the worksheet should not be protected, as it's one I built from scratch and am not hosting on a server anywhere. I can perform an insert on an empty sheet with no issue using: `sht.range((1,1),(2,1)).api.Insert()`, so it must be related to that specific worksheet. I will see if it is marked as protected somewhere.

Comment: There are no protections on the document that I can find. In addition, other VBA commands can be sent to it just fine, namely `range().api.Sort()`. This does not produce the COM error. I thought perhaps this was a similar issue to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223182/sorting-with-xlwings-pywin32 , but all the arguments here are integers (as explicitly demanded by the `int()` functions).

Comment: Replace `range_obj.api.Insert()` with `range_obj.api.Select();import sys;sys.exit()`.  Then go to Excel and right-click inside the selected range and choose `Insert`.  Does that succeed or fail?  If it fails does Excel give a more helpful error message?

Comment: The `Select()` call seems to work, but the exit throws an exception (is there a way to format code in comments? ctrl+k is not working):

"SystemExit

C:\Users\sroy\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\edm\envs\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is simply adding `.EntireColumn` to the range object.

`range_obj.api.EntireColumn.Insert()`

I don't understand why it can figure out that I want the entire column shifted on a sample worksheet but not the actual one I'm working with, but that seems to have been the issue.